# Braintree GraphQL: How to get payment method from Transaction?

Tags: kotlin, graphql, braintree

I'm using the Braintree GraphQL API and Drop-In UI for Javascript. We're offering the following payment methods:

- Credit Card
- PayPal
- Apple Pay
- Google Pay

How can I extract an enum value representing these payment methods from a [Transaction](https://graphql.braintreepayments.com/reference/#object--transaction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Transaction` Object contains the field paymentMethodSnapshot, which can be queried:

```
 query { node(id: "TRANSACTION_GLOBAL_ID"){
  ... on Transaction {
    paymentMethodSnapshot {
      __typename
      ... on CreditCardDetails {
        origin {
          type
        }
      }
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

The different payment methods can be distinguished by evaluating the `__typename`

To detect Google and Apple Pay Payments you can query the `origin.type` field on `CreditCardDetails`, that contains additional information if the credit card was provided from a third-party origin, such as Apple Pay, Google Pay, or another digital wallets.

Comment: I'm getting Error : "An object with this ID was not found."  My ID is in this format -99fkffzn